# Prove $\sin(\pi/2-x)\cot(x+\pi/2) = -\sin(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I've managed to use cofunction identities to get the left side of the equation to (pi/2-x)-tanx. From here, I keep ending up at -cotx? I'm pretty sure that's wrong, and I have no idea how to to go about proving this in another way.

Comment: I think you might have a type in your question. You got to the left hand side to $(pi/2-x)-tanx$?

Comment: It's really easy to show formulas in standard math format here so that people can read them easily. Someone has already helped you with the title. For more about this, see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You're correct to think $-\cot x$ is wrong; how did you get that result? You can edit the question to show step by step what you did.

Comment: @PedroAmaral I don't think I made a typo. Does cot(x+pi/2) not equal -tanx?

Comment: @Gilsin You definitely made a typo, please read carefully your question.

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you!! I did make a typo, I've noticed my error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **hint**,

Try using the following identities
\begin{align*}
\cot(x) &= \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\\
\sin(-x) &= -\sin(x)\\
\cos(-x) &= \cos(x)\\
\sin(x+\pi) &= -\sin(x)\\
\cos(x+\pi) &= -\cos(x) 
\end{align*}

Expand the LHS with the first one, and then try to change some terms (and maybe get them to cancel) by using the phase shift identities

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -x\right) = \cos(x)$$ and $$\cot\left(x +\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -\tan(x)$$

---

Both of the above can be shown using
$$
\sin(x +y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x) \sin(y)
$$
and
$$
\cos(x +y) = \cos(x) \cos(y) - \sin(x) \sin(y)
$$
combined with $\cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ and $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take LHS
First , Sin(π/2 - x) = cosx
Second , cot(π/2+ x) = -tanx because in 2nd quadrant cot is negative so when cot changes to tanx we add extra negative sign.

Now Put -tanx = - sinx / cosx and cancel out cos x from numerator and denominator
hence you got -six in LHS which is equal to RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Just muck it out.

The following are basic identities.

$\sin(\frac \pi 2-x) =\cos x$

$\sin(x+\frac \pi 2) = \cos x$

$\cos(x+\frac \pi  2) = \sin x$.

We can know this by:

1. Rote memory
2. Considering that by considering angles $\frac \pi 2 -x$ or $x +\frac \pi 2$ is simply a matter of rotating a unit circle a quarter turn and possibly reflecting the circle on an axis and thus the $x,y$ cooridinates will "switch".  (It helps to draw a picture.
3. Considering $\sin (A+ B) = \sin A\cos B + \cos A \sin B$ and $\cos (A+B) =\cos A\cos B -\sin A\sin B$ and so

- $\sin (\frac \pi 2 - x) = \sin \frac \pi 2\cos x + \cos \frac \pi 2 \sin(-x)=1\cdot \cos x + 0\cdot (-\sin x) = \cos x$.
- $\sin ( x+ \frac \pi 2) = \sin x\cos \frac \pi 2 + \cos x \sin(\frac \pi 2)=\sin x \cdot 0 + \cos x\cdot 1 = \cos x$
- $\cos(x+ \frac \pi 2) = \cos x\cos\frac \pi 2 - \sin x \sin \frac \pi 2=\cos x \cdot 0 -\sin x \cdot 1=-\sin x$.

ANd as a result of these three identities.

$\sin(\frac \pi -x)\cot (x+\frac \pi 2) = $

$\sin(\frac \pi -x)\frac {\cos (x+\frac \pi 2)}{\sin (x+\frac \pi 2)}=$

$\cos x\frac {-\sin x}{\cos x}= $

$-\sin x$.

That is ..... *IF* $\cos x\ne 0$.  Or in otherwords if $x \ne \pm\frac \pi 2$.

If $x =\pm \frac \pi 2$ then $\cot (x+\frac \pi 2)$ is not defined.